# How to deal with oAuth callbacks to non webservers?

Tags: web-services, oauth, oauth-2.0, oauth-provider, mobile-devices

I'm currently building an oAuth2 server so that external clients/devices can access data from my service without having to send over user credentials with every request. I've finally grasped how oAuth works after spending an entire day reading numerous tutorials and online documentation, however, there's still one thing that I'm rather unsure of...

When sending a request for an authorization code to an oAuth server, how should I deal with a callback to mobile devices and devices that aren't a webserver?

E.g. this request to my oAuth server will send an authorization code as a callback to a specified webserver (http://client-url.com in this case)

```
http://mydomainname/oauth2/?client_id=test&grant_type=authorization_code&client_details=test&redirect_uri=http://client-url.com&response_type=code
```

The server at http://client-url.com will receive a response containing an authorization code and the developer will be able to store a user's oAuth credentials accordingly.

Obviously a mobile device isn't a webserver, so is there a standardised way of dealing with this? I've read online that you can define something called a custom URI scheme within iOS and Android apps. But what about the other mobile platforms out there? And desktop apps? I want my API to be accessible from as many platforms and devices as possible.

The reason why I'm asking this question is because I want to add validation to my oAuth server so that users can only register apps with valid callback URL's. I wasn't sure if should allow any other type of input as a callback apart from a valid URL.

Can anyone shine any light on this? I want to avoid spending hours validating and testing this across all devices as I'm sure anyone that has developed for multiple mobile platforms in the past must have some knowledge about this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: since you're using the authorization_code grant type, aren't you able to uniquely identify valid oAuth clients via their client_id and client_secret combination? Using that combo should omit the need for dealing with redirect URIs.

Comment: @charlesg I think he is referring to the first leg of the 3-legged flow, where the server receives a client_id and a redirect URL in the request, where he needs to check for the equality of the redirect url sent in the request with the redirect URL registered when client id was created.